# data.frame column as parameter of function

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I use a column as a customized function parameter :

```
custom_function <- function(value, group) {
  if (group == "setosa") {
    value*0
  } else if (group == "versicolor") {
    value*1
  } else if (group == "virginica") {
    value*2
  }
}

iris %>%
  mutate(new_column = custom_function(value = Sepal.Length, group = Species))
```

Comment: Your function expects `group` to have length 1, so you need to make that happen. `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(new_column = custom_function(value = Sepal.Length, group = first(Species)))`. Or you could vectorize your function by using the vectorized `ifelse()` (or `dplyr::case_when`) instead of `if(){}else{}`. This is pretty clearly a simple example, so it's hard to know which is more appropriate for your real use-case.

Comment: Your first suggestion is indeed what I was looking for. I'll accept that if you post as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function expects group to have length 1, so you need to make that happen:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% ## 1 Species per group
  mutate(
    ## use first() so only a single value is passed to the group arg
    new_column = custom_function(value = Sepal.Length, group = first(Species))
  )
```

Or you could vectorize your function by using the vectorized `ifelse()` (or `dplyr::case_when`) instead of `if(){}else{}`. This is pretty clearly a simple example, so it's hard to know which is more appropriate for your real use-case.